# Heroku production app: 'Invalid Host Header' with express server and proxy

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a nearly-fresh `create-react-app` project where I've got a simple express server running a test API endpoint:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('build'));
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello From Express');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at: http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

In `package.json` I've added a line, `"proxy": http://localhost:5000",` and it all works fine locally. However when I deploy to Heroku I get 'Invalid Host Header'. How can I change this to work in production?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but one of the many I came across while dealing with this same issue, so I'm sharing what I've learned and hope it will be useful to others.

A working solution is to use http-proxy-middleware to manually set up the proxy. Please see an explanation here: [deploying create-react-app to heroku with express backend returns invalid host header in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845805/deploying-create-react-app-to-heroku-with-express-backend-returns-invalid-host-h)

Here is a minimal working example: https://github.com/sehailey/proxytest
and here is that example deployed: https://proxytest2.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Remove from package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

Add a new file in the root folder named **.env.development** with the contents:

```
HOST=name.herokuapp.com
```