# MERN STACK Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I have been googling and cannot find a solution to my issue.

I AM NEW to the MERN stack, mostly do front end stuff.

This project is created using MongoDB ATLAS, React, Express and node.js

I have the app deployed to heroku, and the app is displaying but I cannot use it, i get the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. But i can see and interact with the front end of it, but the back-end is not working i'm assuming.. I can navigate pages etc.. But when I enter information and try to store it to the server, nothing happens, just the front end portion, but nothing connects or sends to the server, i keep getting that connection refused error. 
Then this error follows immediately after : `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error`

I'm using mongoDB atlas, I'm not sure if that makes a difference there or not. I do believe I set it up to be accessed anywhere too, not just my IP.

Now when I run on my local machine it all works totally fine. IF I'M ON the heroku deployed version, WITH MY local machine server running, it works fine. But as soon as i shut my local server down, that errors comes back on the heroku deployed version.

This is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
/* for heroku deployment */
const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
/* for heroku deployment */
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully")
})

const exerciseRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const userRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/exercises', exerciseRouter);
app.use('/users', userRouter);
/* for heroku deployment */

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  })
}

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`)
});
```

I also tried:

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
})
```

Instead of the conditional.

This is my **backend** package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.12"
  }
}
```

I also tried:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
```

here too.

This is my **Front-end** package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mern-stack-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is a link to the site deployed on heroku if you wish to see for yourself: https://full-stack-exercise-tracker.herokuapp.com/

If you need any more code files from me please just ask. Like I said this is my first ever MERN stack app and MERN stack deployment.

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Without seeing your front end requests, my guess is that your client side requests are pointing to the localhost URL instead of to your deployed application URL. When you build your client-side, you'll want to create a flexible setup that points to localhost in development and points to remote host in production. For example, I use axios as well and I create a custom configuration (`baseURL`): https://github.com/mattcarlotta/SJSITApp/blob/master/client/src/utils/axiosConfig/index.js#L5-L10 which utilizes this: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/SJSITApp/blob/master/client/config/envs.js#L15-L18

Comment: In addition, the `create-react-app` no longer supports a `package.json` proxy, see here for a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845805/deploying-create-react-app-to-heroku-with-express-backend-returns-invalid-host-h/52846108#52846108, although it's not needed if you use the config above (plus you're already using `cors`, so the proxy isn't needed).